# Account extended private key vs BIP32 extended private key

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed

I would like to know which is the difference between Account extended private key and BIP32 extended private key. I was creating Mnemonic seeds (https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) and I stopped because I could not find out the difference

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do with Account Extended Private Key and Account Extended Public Key?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/86089/what-can-i-do-with-account-extended-private-key-and-account-extended-public-key)

Answer (score 1):

BIP 32 extended private key is a more generic term that refers to any private key that is derived and serialized according to BIP 32.

Account extended private key is the BIP 32 extended private key at a specific derivation path. This is described in [BIP 44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki). For P2PKH Bitcoin addresses, this derivation path is `m/44'/0'/0'`.

Comment: OK, so them, which is the difference between Account extended private key and BIP 32 extended private key in the ian coleman example, in which level will be the BIP32 extended private key?

Comment: On the Ian Coleman site, Account Extended Private key is the private key derived at the account derivation path. BIP32 Extended Private Keys are the child private keys that you ultimately use.